# Open or close connection in php 7

Tags: php, oop

I am studying OO in Php. Then I want to learn about how to open and close database connection. I have this code in database.php file:

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "perpustakaan");

public function connectDB(){
     link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user,
          pass, $this->dbname);
     return this->link;
}
```

Then I try this code in another php file:

```
$db = new database();
$link = $db->connectDB();
echo is_resource($link);
if(is_resource($link)) {
    echo "open ";
} else {
    echo "close ";
}
$link->close();
if(is_resource($link)){
    echo "open";
} else {
    echo "close";
}
```

But the result is:

> close close

What's wrong? Is my connection database success or not?

Comment: `new mysqli` returns an object, not a resource. So `is_resource` is false.

Comment: What database? What driver mysqli, PDO ....? It will be interpreted line by line, logically if close is called, it should have already been closed after that line.

Comment: One of the ways is to check the `connect_error` property of the mysqli object when you created the connection to the database.

Comment: If I want to use PDO, where I can learn it for open and close connection?